# Unable to see the LLMNR query response?

Tags: networking, network-programming, scapy, service-discovery

I am sending the (llmnr) query over my local network, i can see the query in packet capturing tool(wire shark).But never seen/got any LLMNR response query.i have quarried for win 10 system and one hp printer.so the question is does ever LLMNR query get response because i tried to capture the LLMNR traffic in multiple networks and i have never seen any response packets

Pasting the code here :

```
class LLMNRQuery(Packet):
    name = "Link Local Multicast Node Resolution - Query"
    fields_desc = [ShortField("id", 0),
                   BitField("qr", 0, 1),
                   BitEnumField("opcode", 0, 4, {0: "QUERY"}),
                   BitField("c", 0, 1),
                   BitField("tc", 0, 2),
                   BitField("z", 0, 4),
                   BitEnumField("rcode", 0, 4, {0: "ok"}),
                   DNSRRCountField("qdcount", None, "qd"),
                   DNSRRCountField("ancount", None, "an"),
                   DNSRRCountField("nscount", None, "ns"),
                   DNSRRCountField("arcount", None, "ar"),
                   DNSQRField("qd", "qdcount"),
                   DNSRRField("an", "ancount"),
                   DNSRRField("ns", "nscount"),
                   DNSRRField("ar", "arcount", 0)]
    overload_fields = {UDP: {"sport": 5355, "dport": 5355}}


bind_bottom_up(UDP, LLMNRQuery(), dport=5355)
bind_bottom_up(UDP, LLMNRQuery(), sport=5355)
bind_layers(UDP, LLMNRQuery(), sport=5355, dport=5355)


def hashret(self):
    return struct.pack("!H", self.id)


def qtype_sendPacket(qname='localhost', qtype='A'):
    packet = IP(src='192.168.1.10', dst="224.0.0.252")/UDP() / LLMNRQuery(id=RandShort(), qd=DNSQR(qname=qname, qtype=qtype))
    send(packet, verbose=False)
##################

qtypelist = ["ANY", "AAAA", "PTR", "SRV", "A", "TXT"]
    for i in qtypelist:
        qtype_sendPacket('SAHAYRU', i)
```

Comment: Your question is really too broad to answer without knowing the code, what the query looks like, and the address to which it is sent. Also, do you have a responder configured on the network? What is its configuration?

Comment: Thanks Ron,i have added the code as well